# Evaluating whether a page is the result of a referral from a particular page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, postback

I have an Edit Profile page which allows users to change their information - currently it only allows users who have a record in the table 'userprofiles' to edit their information. I want newly registered users to be able to edit their profiles as well.

At the minute, I am using the ASP.NET membership system with the appropriate asp.net_ tables in an Access database to store user credentials. The 'userprofiles' table is a separate table which has more personal information in it. There is no link between the two tables

Here is my code behind:

> ```
> Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
>
>     If IsCrossPagePostBack Then
>         SeparateNewUserFunction()
>         Return
>     End If
>     If Not IsPostBack Then
>         DisplayData()
>         SaveConfirmation.Visible = False
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

And here is my DisplayData() function just if anyone was interested as to what it does:

> ```
>     Protected Sub DisplayData()
>     Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
>     Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM userprofiles WHERE TravellerName=@f1"
>     Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", User.Identity.Name)
>     conn.Open()
>     Dim profileDr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
>     profileDr.Read()
>     Dim newEmailAddress = ""
>     Dim newDescription = ""
>     If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("EmailAddress")) Then newEmailAddress = profileDr.Item("EmailAddress")
>     If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("Description")) Then newDescription = profileDr.Item("Description")
>     If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("AvatarURL")) Then ProfilePic.ImageUrl = profileDr.Item("AvatarURL")
>     description.Text = newDescription
>     email.Text = newEmailAddress
>     conn.Close()
>
> End Sub
> ```

Rather than checking if a record exists in the 'userprofiles' table that matches the User.Identity.Name of the current user, I thought it would be easier just to evaluate whether or not the user had just been redirected from the Register.aspx page. (If this evaluation is true, then as you can see above, a separate "New User" function will be called).

That is my logic, but I have no clue if VB.NET has a "referrer" or "isReferred" expression? (at the minute as you can see I thought isCrossPagePostback might be the right thing but no luck!)

Any ideas?

Comment: I would also strongly recommend learning [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) along side, or soon after you get comfortable with Web Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether or not a record exists and base your logic on that. That is the only right way to do it. As in:

1. What if you introduce a new page to handle registrations? This logic breaks.
2. What if you one day you retire and the next guy decides to rename the Register.aspx page? This logic breaks.
3. What if user hits back button and clicks the Register button again? This logic may break.

You should also consider a foreign key and unique constraint on that table, as well as using UserId instead of TravellerName. TravellerName can change, UserId will not.

... and yes you can the referring page by using [HttpRequest.ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx), which gets you a list of [IIS Server Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx).